# Using has_many through with nested namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a nested model like so:

```
class Games::Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :games_extras_achievements_players, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer'
  has_many :games_extras_achievements, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::Achievement',:through=>:games_extras_achievements_players
  validates :user_id,uniqueness: true
end

class Games::Extras::Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games_extras_achievements_players, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer'
  has_many :games_players, through: :games_extras_achievements_players, class_name: 'Games::Player'
end

class Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :games_extras_achievement_id, :games_player_id
  belongs_to :games_extras_achievement, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::Achievement'
  belongs_to :games_player, :class_name => 'Games::Player'
end
```

Objects on the join class work as expected.

However trying to get player -> achievement or vice versa gives an error:

```
> p.games_extras_achievements
  Games::Extras::Achievement Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "games_extras_achievements".* FROM "games_extras_achievements" INNER JOIN "games_extras_achievements_players" ON "games_extras_achievements"."id" = "games_extras_achievements_players"."games_extras_achievement_id" WHERE "games_extras_achievements_players"."player_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column games_extras_achievements_players.player_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ents_players"."games_extras_achievement_id" WHERE "games_ext...
```

If I change the migration to use `player_id` like it is trying to find, I get an error stating that `games_player_id does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it.

I needed to use the non-namespaced column names and add a foreign key constraint.

```
class Games::Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :games_extras_achievements_players, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer'
  has_many :games_extras_achievements, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::Achievement',:through=>:games_extras_achievements_players
  validates :user_id,uniqueness: true
end

class Games::Extras::Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games_extras_achievements_players, :class_name => 'Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer'
  has_many :games_players, through: :games_extras_achievements_players, class_name: 'Games::Player'
end

class Games::Extras::AchievementsPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :achievement_id, :player_id
  belongs_to :games_extras_achievement, class_name:'Games::Extras::Achievement',foreign_key: :achievement_id
  belongs_to :games_player, class_name: 'Games::Player',foreign_key: :player_id
end
```

Hopefully this will save someone some aggravation.

Comment: This answer needs to include the migration or SQL table definition in order to be a complete solution.